# jenkins - gitparam jobdsl - branchFilter

Tags: jenkins, job-dsl

I want to fill branchFilter automatically on Jenkins using JobDSL plugin and language.

This is the url of Jenkins Job DSL plugin:

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.FreeStyleJob.parameters-gitParam

I want to select all branches but master. To do that I have written the following lines:

```
  //This Build is parametrized
  parameters {
      gitParam('branch') { // https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.BuildParametersContext.gitParam
          description('Git Branch')
          type('BRANCH')
          branchFilter("^(?!.*master).*$")
      }
  }
```

But when compiling it I get error that such method is not available.

> Processing provided DSL script ERROR: (script, line 28) No signature
>   of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.GitParamContext.branchFilter()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [*]
>   Possible solutions: tagFilter(java.lang.String)

[image]

Is there any workaround to do this automatically on the script or we have to fulfill that field after job has been created?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did:

```java
gitParameter {
            // The name of the parameter.
            name('SELECTED_BRANCH')
            // The type of the list of parameters: Tag - list of all commit tags in repository - returns Tag Name Branch - list of all branch in repository - returns Branch Name Revision - list of all revision sha1 in repository followed by its author and date - returns Tag SHA1
            type('PT_BRANCH')
            // In my case this is a variable pointing to the gitlab hook variable
            defaultValue('$gitlabAfter')
            // A description that will be shown to the user later.
            description('Select a git the configuration you want to deploy')
            // Name of branch to look in.
            branch('')
            // Regex used to filter displayed branches.
            // Whatever is captured in the group will be the name used as the value of the SELECTED_BRANCH
            branchFilter('origin/(config\\/.*)')
            // This parameter is used to get tag from git.
            tagFilter('*')
            // Select how to sort the downloaded parameters.
            sortMode('NONE')
            // Which value is selected, after loaded parameters.
            selectedValue('NONE')
            // If in the task are defined multiple repositories, this option specifies which the repository is taken into account on getting data.
            useRepository("<my git url>.*")
            // When this option is enabled will show a text field.
            quickFilterEnabled(false)
            // Specify the number of items the list will display.
            // listSize(String value)
        }
```

As strange as it seems, some parameters shouldn't really be necessary, but the plugin requires them anyway, so that's why the config is verbose.

Also, pay attention that this one is `gitParameter` and not `gitParam`, yes, both exist, and they take different parameters.

For more information about the properties you can go here:

https://plugins.jenkins.io/git-parameter/

Answer (score 0):

```java
    parameters {
        gitParameter {
            name('selected')
            type('BRANCH')
            defaultValue('master')
            description('')
            branch('')
            branchFilter('origin')  
            tagFilter('*')
            sortMode('NONE')
            selectedValue('NONE')
            useRepository("")
            quickFilterEnabled(false) 
        }
```

Using this syntax it’s able to create a configuration inside the Jenkins job, but once I trigger that job , this configuration is getting removed automatically is there any solution to retain the configuration for every builds